# Div height doesn't get recalculated on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

It works perfectly when I refresh the page, but when I resize it doesn't recalculate the div height.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dfn5b1p8/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectorsArray = ['home', 'about', 'portfolio', 'contact'];
    responsiveResize(selectorsArray);  
$(window).resize(function(){
    var selectorsArray = ['home', 'about', 'portfolio', 'contact'];
    responsiveResize(selectorsArray);  
});
});


function responsiveResize(selectorsArray){
    $.each(selectorsArray, function( index, value ) {
        var cntcnter = $('#'+value+' .content-container');
        var height = $('#'+value+' .content-container').height();
        console.log(height);
        cntcnter.css({'height': height+'px', 'margin-top': '-'+(height/2) +'px'});
    });
}
```

Comment: the page doesn't contains [about, portfolio etc]. so those strings are generating null value (see in console) and blocking your way form running it properly. try this  http://jsfiddle.net/dfn5b1p8/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working is because on the first run, you set a `height` to the container. On the second run, it already has a `height` set so it's always the same value. If the text overflows the container, it's not affecting the new height in this case.

If you want to keep using your code, you need to clear/remove the `height` you added on the previous run.

You can use this

```
var height = $('#'+value+' .content-container').css('height', '').height();
```

Like Chris Empx mentioned, this is easily obtainable with CSS.

Also, you could optimize the code like [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dfn5b1p8/4/)

Answer (score 1):

i wonder why you want to do that with jquery.
i would do that in css.

like that

```
<div class='container'>
   <div class='column col 12'>
       <p>Your Inputs here</p>
   </div>
<div class='clear'></div>
</div>
```

then this in css

```
    .container {
         margin: 0 auto;
         width: 960px;
    }
    .col-12{
         width: 100%;
    }
.clear {clear: both;}
.column {padding: 0 .8em; float:left;}
```

col-6 would be width:50%
col-3 would be width:25%

Comment: sorry i frogot:
that will be responsive, but you might add *{box-sizing: border-box;} and for responsive images: img{max-width:100%; height:auto;}

Comment: the margin left and right would be equal.
the height would depend on the content inside the div.
but there is a script i found you may can try:

http://blog.niklaskoehler.de/entwicklung/div-elemente-mit-hilfe-von-jquery-auf-die-gleiche-hohe-setzen.html

there is also an example

Comment: Ah yes but if I would use javascript anyway my script works now thanks to the tip of vxy.ca! Thanks for the help of both of you.